# Split a String in Bigquery? (Split on character numbers instead of delimiter)?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following dataset:

| Column1             |
| 100BB7832036 B120501|

I would like the output to look like:

|column 1    | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 |

|100BB7832036|    B        | 1205     | 01       |

I am having trouble splitting this string as the only delimiter is ' ', and I am not sure if it is possible to split this string based on the character values (ex: values 0-11 would give 100BB7832036, and value 13 would give B, and values 14-17 would give 1205, and values 18-19 would give 01)

So far I have tried:

split(column, ' ')[offset(0)] as Colum1
split(column, ' ')[offset(1)] as Column2

however this results in

| Column 1    | Column 2 |

| 100BB7832036|          |

where column 2 is blank

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR` function to split string into column(s) with this syntax

```
SUBSTR(column, start, [length])
```

Feel free to adjust the start index and length for your use case.

```
with example as (
  select "100BB7832036 B120501" as column1
)
select 
substr(column1, 0, 13) as col1,
substr(column1,14, 1) as col2,
substr(column1,15, 4) as col3,
substr(column1,19) as col3,
from example
```

Output:

```
col1            col2    col3    col4
100BB7832036    B       1205    01
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: The starting index for the `col4` should be 19 in the picture to get your expected result. But yeah, you got the idea.